# How to change volume level of non-default sound device programmatically?

Tags: c++, winapi, audio, volume

I can change volume level of default sound device on windows by C++ programmatically using `IAudioEndpointVolume` and `SetMasterVolumeLevel()` method.

How to change volume level of **non-default** sound devices, on PC with several sound cards?

Comment: this is generally a Very Bad Idea, mate. Unless you're writing drivers etc., leave the ability to manage the volume levels to the user.

Comment: What keeps you from calling `SetMasterVolumeLevel()` on the `IAudioEndpointVolume` interface referring to the desired audio device?

Comment: @IInspectable , i can get the list of devices but don't know how to select another sound device from this list to change its volume level. 
I tried select it using `IMMDeviceEnumerator` and `GetDevice()` method to get non-default device but it crashes when executing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it, this is my code:

```
HRESULT hr = S_OK;
IMMDeviceEnumerator *pEnumerator = NULL;
IMMDeviceCollection *pCollection = NULL;
IMMDevice *pEndpoint = NULL;
IPropertyStore *pProps = NULL;
LPWSTR pwszID = NULL;
CoInitialize(NULL);

hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator, NULL,CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator,(void**)&pEnumerator);
hr = pEnumerator->EnumAudioEndpoints(eRender, DEVICE_STATE_ACTIVE,&pCollection); // ** use "eCapture" for microphones and "eRender" for speakers.
hr = pCollection->GetCount(&count);
if (count == 0){
   cout <<"No endpoints found."<<endl;
}
 for (ULONG i = 0; i < count; i++){
    hr = pCollection->Item(i, &pEndpoint);
    hr = pEndpoint->GetId(&pwszID);
    IAudioEndpointVolume *endpointVolume = NULL;
    pEnumerator->GetDevice(pwszID,&pEndpoint);
    pEndpoint->Activate(__uuidof(IAudioEndpointVolume),CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, NULL, (LPVOID *)&endpointVolume);
    hr = pEndpoint->OpenPropertyStore(STGM_READ, &pProps);
    PROPVARIANT varName;
    PropVariantInit(&varName);
    hr = pProps->GetValue(PKEY_Device_FriendlyName, &varName);
    printf("Endpoint %d: \"%S\" (%S)\n",i, varName.pwszVal, pwszID);
    CoTaskMemFree(pwszID);
    pwszID = NULL;
    PropVariantClear(&varName);
    endpointVolume->SetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(0.1, NULL); // set volume level of device to 0.1 (10%) 
   // endpointVolume->Release();
   //you can save endpointVolume in a container to set set volume level for each device.
}
```